# Show spinner for loading image to get width/height?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, browser, frontend

In a `react` application I need to go from page A to page B in an SPA, and to go from A to B the clicks a button to upload an image. This is the trigger to go to from A to B.

But before either going to B or displaying the components in B I need to need to get the `height` and `width` of the image. Because this is an asynchronous process, although it should be very fast in 99% of cases, do I need to put a spinner?

Or is it better to just disable the interactive inputs on page B without a spinner temporarily until the image width/height is determined, or maybe delay the switch from page A to B until the image width/height is determined without a spinner?

I'm torn because if it is a very, very fast process - which it likely should be in most cases, I would hate to throw up a spinner just for a split second.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a design question. However, adding a spinner is not that difficult and may provide a better UX for when the process is unexpectedly slow.